# Scala Spark, fill a entire column with a char value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a column, and if in that column there is a "Y" i will fill the new column with "Y" otherwise i will fill it with "N".

```
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|Date          |        Value        | HasChanged        |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|2020-12-14    |        N            |     Y             |
|2020-12-14    |        Y            |     Y             |
|2020-12-14    |        N            |     Y             |
|2020-12-14    |        N            |     Y             |

+--------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|Date          |        Value        | HasChanged        |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|2020-12-14    |        N            |     N             |
|2020-12-14    |        N            |     N             |
|2020-12-14    |        N            |     N             |
|2020-12-14    |        N            |     N             |
```

I am trying with this:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("HasChanged", when(Value === "Y"), lit("Y")).otherwise("N")))
```

But only changes the row where there is a Y and what i want is change the entire Column. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether value = Y in all rows. You can do that using the maximum of the comparison boolean over a window, which will be True if 1 or more rows are True, and False if every row is False.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = df.withColumn(
    "HasChanged",
    when(max($"Value" === "Y").over(Window.orderBy()), "Y").otherwise("N")
)

df1.show

+----------+-----+----------+
|      Date|Value|HasChanged|
+----------+-----+----------+
|2020-12-14|    N|         Y|
|2020-12-14|    Y|         Y|
|2020-12-14|    N|         Y|
|2020-12-14|    N|         Y|
+----------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `when` actually, you can just use `max` function as `Y > N`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = df.withColumn("HasChanged", max(col("Value")).over(Window.orderBy()))

df1.show

//+----------+-----+----------+
//|      Date|Value|HasChanged|
//+----------+-----+----------+
//|2020-12-14|    N|         Y|
//|2020-12-14|    Y|         Y|
//|2020-12-14|    N|         Y|
//|2020-12-14|    N|         Y|
//+----------+-----+----------+
```